# Login via facebook/google?

Tags: extensions, extension-request

Can someone recommend working extensions for login via facebook/google?
I've tried some but they are either not working or not working very well.

Firstly I tried Akeeba Social Login. After I install and enable the plugin, on the login page the facebook login button appears next to the login button, but when I click it there is an error message from facebook saying URL not whitelisted. I check Akeeba's page, but there is no documentation regarding how to set the whitelist. Besides I find that Akeeba seems not maintaining this plugin any more, it doesn't even appear in its product list. So I've decided not to use this plugin.

Next I tried the two free extensions that appear when you search "social login" on Joomla's extension directory, they are "social login" by thekrotek and "miniorange social login" by xecurify. For both of them settings are easy, I just input the App ID and Secret like I did with Akeeba Social Login. However, this time the facebook login button won't even show up on my frontend. I've sent emails to both company but no response yet.

Can someone recommend working social login extension? What I want is very simple - just login via facebook/google, so I prefer free extensions if possible. Or if you have experience with the two extensions I mention above, please share.

Comment: https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/akeeba-sociallogin

Answer (score 1):

First of all I do not think that there would be any relevant problem with **Akeeba Social Login** extension. I personally have not used that (I’ll give you below what I use) but knowing Akeeba, their extensions work well. @Lodder provided a link to their extension under your post and it shows that the Social Login extension was updated 4 months ago which means that it is maintained quite well (considering the fact also that in the last months Joomla is getting patches only, not any major updates, so these smaller extensions do not require too many updates now).

What I can suspect is that you missed few points at installation and the setting of the extension. Particularly, you have to create an app at [Facebook Developer page](https://developers.facebook.com/) (you already made it). Please give special attention to set the callback URL (a valid redirect URI) correctly at Client OAuth settings of your Facebook App.

In Akeeba documentation the steps are quite clear about what and how to do: https://github.com/akeeba/sociallogin/wiki/Facebook

On the “URL not whitelisted...” problem, according to Akeeba docs the correct callback url setting in you Facebook App (app dashboard->Facebook Login->Settings) is like:

> > Find the Valid OAuth redirect URIs option. You will need to enter a URL in the form http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_ajax&group=sociallogin&plugin=facebook&format=raw replacing http://www.example.com with the real URL of your site.

If you follow the steps precisely your social login should work. But:

The second option which I have been using years ago now is the OneAll social network integration:

https://www.oneall.com/

Info for Joomla: https://docs.oneall.com/plugins/guide/social-login-joomla/

They provide free accounts (limited but basically enough). Only for “social login” visitors with unbelievable amount of networks it is more than enough and you can use that for free on many sites too. They also provide very good documentation for setting up their service and the setup is very similar to Akeeba. They also give you free Joomla extensions (a component and a modul). And they also update continually. The setup should not be more than 20-40 minutes including creating the facebook app for example. I prefer this solution because you can use this under many frameworks/web engines, with the use of one nicely built dashboard at OneAll and you also do not have to worry about Facebook API updates and changing integration problems, this company solves that.

I hope that you can move forward well with the above info.